# Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., …] : Subscript out of bounds - Eventstudy package

Tags: r, bounds

I'm getting an issue running my code in R. I'm using the event study package and every-time that I try to make it run with the marketmodel approach by adding an market index to the code I get this error :

> Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., …] : Subscript out of bounds

Both of my dataset are zoo object :

1. one for my return : 286 observation by columns for 4 columns
2. one for my index : 286 observation and 1 columns

their is my code :

```
library(eventstudies)
library(psych)
library(dplyr)
library(hflights)
library(zoo)
install.packages("AbnormalReturns")
#First step of the process not implementing any model in eventstudy package    
dataframe <-data.frame( name = Data_test1$name, when=Data_test1$when,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Zoo.data<-zoo(x=StockReturns,order.by = Dates$Date, frequency = NULL)    

new.data<-eventstudy(firm.returns = Zoo.data,event.list = dataframe,
           event.window = 5,
           type = "None",
           to.remap = TRUE,
           remap = "cumsum",
           inference = TRUE,
           inference.strategy = "bootstrap")

#Using the market model to obtain more statistically relevant result.Incorporating an Index data for benchmark
#Erreur je dois redefinir ma data set pour le MSCI sans les dates et créer un zoo event en utilisant les dates 


Msci.zoo<-zoo(x = MSCI_test, order.by = Dates$Date, frequency = NULL)

Marketmodels<-eventstudy(firm.returns =Zoo.data,
                               event.list = dataframe,
                             event.window = 5,
                             type = "marketModel",
                              to.remap = TRUE,
                              remap = "cumsum",
                              inference = TRUE,
                            inference.strategy = "bootsrap",
           model.args = list(market.returns = Msci.zoo[, "MXEU Index                                                      ...1", drop = FALSE]))
```

If anybody could help me it would be great

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar issue and was able to locate the problem in the list for the *event.list* argument.

Even though the respective list looked "visually good", it was saved as a tibble, while the function requires a regular data frame. I used the following command to convert the list into the "correct" format:

```
dataframe <- as.data.frame(dataframe)
```